# Rails Capistrano: Steps after Deployment (Getting remote server up)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3.2, capistrano

Ok. This should be my easiest stackoverflow post yet.

So I have Capistrano installed and configured properly.  I've managed a successful deployment to my remote server (incidentally that remote server is running rails 4.0 and the local one was on 3.2.13). All my files appear to have been successfully transferred to my liquid_admin/current directory (they used to just be in the liquid_admin directory... but whatever.)

So what do I do now? How do I get rails server to load the app in liquid_admin/current?

If I try to do "rails server" it just tells me:

```
usage: rails new app_path
```

Would that actually overwrite my old app? Basically all I want to do is load the app in the "current" directory. Run the server.  Should be a no-brainer right? :)

Comment: could just tell me what all the step you followed after this ? I am getting same problem.where i need to run  `sudo passenger-install-nginx-module` command.

Comment: You just have to run it on the remote server and yous should be fine. It'll tell you what you then have to copy and paste into either apache (which is what I went with) or Nginx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single website on a small server, passenger and Ngnix look like winners.

```
sudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

And then on the Nginx sites folder:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.mysite.com;
        root /rails_website_root/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
}
```

Then just start Ngnix (usually you put it on autostart)

Comment: Thanks! I forgot all about passenger. :)

Answer (score 0):

The default server that you probably use in development - WEBrick - is not suitable for production. Some options that you have are:

- Unicorn
- Thin

You also need Apache or Nginx 'in front' of your Rails server.
All this is well explained in tons of guides, books, railscasts etc, so please go and google it.